# Read First 10 Lines in a File; If Shorter Only Read Those Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, readline

I want to open a file, and read the first 10 lines of a file. If a file has less than 10 lines it should read as many lines as it has. Each line has to be numbered, wether it's text or it's whitespace. Because I have to strip each line, I can't differentiate between an empty string, and the end of a file. For example if I read a file with only three lines, it will print out lines 1 - 10, with lines 4 - 10 being empty, but I would like to have it stop after reaching that 3rd line, as that would be the end of the file. I would really appreciate any help, thank you.

```
def get_file_name():
    fileName = input('Input File Name: ')
    return fileName

def top(fileName):
    try:
        file = open(fileName, 'r')
        line = 'text'
        cnt = 1

        while cnt <= 10: 
            if line != '': 
                line = file.readline()
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                print(str(cnt) + '.', line)
                cnt += 1
            else:
                line = file.readline()
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                print(str(cnt) + '.', line)
                cnt += 1
        file.close()
    except IOError:
        print('FILE NOT FOUND ERROR:', fileName)

def main():
    fileName = get_file_name()
    top(fileName)

main()
```

Comment: Maybe `for i, line in zip(range(10), file)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def read_lines():
    f = open("file-name.txt","r")
    num = 1

    for line in f:
        if num > 10:
            break
        print("LINE NO.",num, ":",line)
        num = num + 1

    f.close()
```

Here, the loop exits at the end of the file. So if you only had 7 lines, it will exit automatically after the 7th line.
However, if you have 10 or more than 10 lines then the "num" variable takes care of that.
EDIT: I have edited the print statement to include the line count as well and started the line count with 1.

Comment: Remember to close the file : ) or use a context manager (with)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    cnt = 1
    for line in f:
        if cnt <= 10:
            print(str(cnt) + '.', line, end='')
            cnt += 1
        else:
            break
```

This should do exactly what you need. You can always remove the if/else and then it will read exactly however many lines are in the file. Example:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    cnt = 1
    for line in f:
        print(str(cnt) + '.', line, end='')
        cnt += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load all the lines into array, count the total line and use an if statement to check if total is 10 or not, then finally use a for loop like `for i in range (0,9):` to print the lines.